# Does gdb support loading an extension dll/so like windbg

Tags: c++, gdb, shared-libraries, coredump

Windbg has a command "Load Extension DLL" as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-load---loadby--load-extension-dll-
The command will load a dll and extend the windbg with extra commands/power.

Does gdb support the same thing too? I want to extend the gdb with extra functionalities like core analyzer in https://github.com/yanqi27/core_analyzer.

But the core analyzer requires that I build the gdb by myself which is tedious. If there is something in the gdb like "load extension DLL" from the windgb?

With that, I don't need to build the gdb by myself, I just need to load the shared library that has more functionalities.

Other approaches that can call functions from an outside shared library are appreciated. I know gdb supports python scripting out of the box. But the C++ code called by the Python script will need to call the API from the gdb. Is there any public API from the gdb, i.e, is there a shared library that exposed the gdb functionalities.?

Comment: gdb exposes its API through Python. The C++ code called from Python needs to call Python back.

Comment: core_analyzer says it `supports gdb's python extension`, so I wonder what you're missing from the gdb Python API.

Comment: @ssbssa, We need to build the gdb with the core analyzer. I was thinking that how to avoid building the gdb but still be able to use the core analyzer functionalities with any gdb by loading the core analyzer into the gdb.

Comment: Oh, that's not how I understood it when I read it `supports gdb's python extension`, I thought it just uses the available python functions to implement their additional commands. But instead they add some additional source files to the gdb sources. In that case, yes, it's not possible to `load an extension DLL` in gdb.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any public API from the gdb, i.e, is there a shared library that exposed the gdb functionalities.?

No.

You can load any code as a Python extension, but there is no `C/C++` API in GDB.

You may have better luck with LLDB.

Comment: OK, I might need to try LLDB in the future.